# Error installing Ubuntu 14.04 the failing step is select and install software

Tags: server, 14.04, system-installation

Installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 and encountered the message below all the time.

```
Installation step failed an installation step failed. you can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: select and install software
```

Install from USB using `unetbootin` with the following setting:

```
Distribution: Ubuntu - 14.04_HdMedia
DiskImage: ISO <Path_to_Ubuntu_ISO>
```

This is a fresh install on a Desktop doesn't have OS. I've searched Google and found some sites but nothing helpful. Any advice on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: From the list the softwares select some and continue the installation process.

Comment: i tried all of the options below Install and none of them works.

Answer (score 2):

Just gone through this myself.

I had to try several different USB sticks before I found one that worked.

I also found that it only worked if I created the installation disk from within an existing Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Good to know Dan, i actually just installed an older version of Ubuntu and upgraded it to 14.04. Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 2):

I've found that unetbootin doesn't wipe the USB drive before installing and it gets confused. On my Windows 7 machine, I open a Command Prompt window with Admin privileges. Type in the following commands:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk ##
```

(Make sure you select the number from the above list that represents your USB drive! Mine was disk 3 so I used `select disk 3`.)

```
clean
create part primary
exit
```

This wipes the partitions and allows a fresh install. Use Windows File Explorer to format the USB drive with default settings. Then run unetbootin. This solved my issues with installing 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to install connected to internet ?
- Did you try to install from USB Stick ? I think its much more stable than usual DVD Driver, especially on old or heavy used computers

Sorry my newbie help, im new but these things solved my problems once.

Comment: This computer doesn't have internet connection. Currently don't have DVDs/CDs am just stuck with USB installation.